# Does Initial Catalog parameter in conection string restrict access to other database?

Tags: sql, connection-string

So if my connection string is

```
Data Source=10.8.4.10;Initial Catalog=DB1;User ID=user;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

I will only be able to query tables from wihthin DB1 or can I query tables from DB2 as well, providing that I will use full path to the tables

```
DB2.tblTableInDb2
```

Comment: `Initial` is being used with the conventional English meaning.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Data Source=10.8.4.10;Initial Catalog=DB1;User ID=user;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
Data Source=10.8.4.10;Initial Catalog=DB2;User ID=user;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

Use another connection string for DB2.